# Converting HTML to Wordpress theme: integrating pages function and using its text editor, conditional enqueuing

Tags: pages, css, javascript

Recently I attempted to convert my static HTML to a Wordpress theme but to no avail.  I was able to understand how to separate my code for my header, content, and footer, and I integrated the header and footer with the `home.php`.  However, now I want to create new pages using the text editor in Wordpress and input the text/HTML into an area in the file.  I created a template already, for the new pages, but I do not know the php to integrate it into the file.

Also, I don't quite understand how to use the conditional `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` functions.  I would like to make a parent page, then have all of its children have those CSS/JS files.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For editing content, I used the plugin Advanced Custom Fields.

As for the conditionals, I just added `if (is_page_template('template_name.php')` before each `wp_enqueue_script`.